# Jenkins is unable to locate file that can be located manually

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

When I added the commands that I use manually at the command prompt to run my project to Jenkins, Jenkins is unable to find the file that's referenced.

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.631 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] main(test.java.IterateToEAMethods)  Time elapsed: 0.016 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Q:\A_Parts routing\03_Systeme\Selenium\Vega Automatisierung Teil 1\AutomatisierterSteuerungsantrag.xls (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at test.java.IterateToEAMethods.main(IterateToEAMethods.java:162)
```

When I run this project through the command line using the exact same commands it runs fine.

```
CD C:\Users\D171_o_QECJACK031\eclipse-workspace\VegaAutomatisierungPart2
mvn --settings settings.xml compile clean test
```

Does anyone know how to get Jenkins to have access to the file?

None of my other projects that use files have this problem and they run through Jenkins.

Comment: Just to be sure: the file and Jenkins are on the same machine?

Comment: yes they are on the same machine

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `\` with `\\` when accessing paths in windows.
You could use `dir` with the path where your scripts are present :

```
// dir("<Your path where scripts are present>")
dir ("C:\\Users\\D171_o_QECJACK031\\eclipse-workspace\\VegaAutomatisierungPart2"){
     <Your commands>
 }
```

Comment: @AlChristopher did you put in the ``dir`` block and executed?

Comment: Is that supposed to be added in Jenkins where the windows batch command is?

Comment: I tried putting that in Jenkins and it still gave the same error message about being unable to find the file.

Comment: @AlChristopher It seems it is unable to find this path ``Q:\A_Parts routing\03_Systeme\Selenium\Vega Automatisierung Teil 1\AutomatisierterSteuerungsantrag.xls``. Can you put `\\` here instaead of `\` and also you can remove the space between the folder ``Vega Automatisierung Teil `` and check if this file exists